# Parâmetros no URL usando /

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, route

Preciso ter um URL no seguinte formato:

> nomedosite.com/note/{qualquercoisa}

Preciso que esse URL dispare o controller `Note`, com a action `Index`. Como devo configurar a minha rota?

tentei usar isto:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OpenNote",
            url: "{controller}/{*stringNote}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Note", action = "Index", stringNote = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

mas recebo sempre a página 404, ou seja, não está funcionando como eu quero. Como devo configurar a minha rota?

Comment: Esse **qualquercoisa** vai ser uma string passada? porque tem um **asterisco**?

Comment: sim é uma string, tem asterisco porque estava no tutorial que seguia, mas eu experimentei sem ele e também não deu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando preciso montar rotas com um parâmetro apenas faço da seguinte forma:

Invés de deixar o `controller` dinâmico eu já forço a rota do `controller`, também adiciono `constraints` para que aceite apenas letras

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "OpenNote",
           url: "Note/{stringNote}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Note", action = "Index" },
           constraints: new { stringNote= @"[aA-zZ]" }
       );
```

Um ponto muito importante é que as rotas customizadas **devem sempre vir antes da rota default** porque ele sempre "bate" na primeira rota que consegue

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "OpenNote",
           url: "Note/{stringNote}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Note", action = "Index" },
           constraints: new { stringNote= @"[aA-zZ]" }
       );


routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: "devem sempre vir antes da rota default" era isso! depois desta vou tirar um curso em mvc xD